# rosserial and custom message: cannot load package error

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to set an arduino node. Here is the short version of the story.

I defined a custom message ("lowlevel/Arduino") and generated the
appropriate header using the script for that. The arduino code
compiles alright. However, I am having a problem on the python_node
side: it cannot load my package 'lowlevel':

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1314328569.317936] Cannot import package : lowlevel
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1314328569.318390] Failed to parse subscriber.
```

However, if I run the following commands in ipython, it seems to work:

```
In [1]: import roslib; roslib.load_manifest("rosserial_python")
In [2]: import rospy
In [3]: roslib.load_manifest('lowlevel')
In [4]: m=__import__('lowlevel.msg')
In [5]: m.msg.Arduino
Out[5]: <class 'lowlevel.msg._Arduino.Arduino'>
```

What am I doing wrong? I did 'rosmake lowlevel' btw.
This happens in diamondback, with ubuntu 10.04 packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11023/rosserial-and-custom-message:-cannot-load-package-error/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2011-08-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2011-09-04**:
And I confirm: if I run the rosserial_python from a different directory than my package directory, it works.

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2011-09-04**:
I mailed you the whole package. the message definition is in the msg folder, when I run rosmake, it creates a msg_gen folder with the cpp and lisp definitions, but the python message definition go to src/lowlevel/msg. Is that wrong? How can I fix?

**Comment by [adasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/52/adasta/) on 2011-09-03**:
I am not sure if I understand what you just said: ", lowlevel.msg is not found because it is in the src subdirectory"   Msg descriptions need to be put in the msg folder.  Python =msg generator looks there for the message.  Could you just email your packag/code?  adasta@gmail.com

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2011-09-03**:
If all of that is correct (I am currently not in front of my work computer so I can't test), then it seems that testing if the package is in the path and skipping the load_manifest call if it is is not a good idea...

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2011-09-03**:
Which makes me think: how come my package is in my path? I posit that it's because it's the current directory. So if I run from the 'lowlevel' directory then it is in the path and then load_manifest is not called. In that case, lowlevel.msg is not found because it is in the src subdirectory.

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2011-09-03**:
Nevertheless I found something. I the load_pkg_module function, my package is actually found in the path (in_path is True at the end of the for loop). Therefore, the manifest is not loaded and the **import** call fails. If however I do call load_manifest(package), the **import** call succeeds.

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2011-09-03**:
I can post my code, but where? Here we are limited to a few characters only... Besides, I don't think the code will help, you would also need my message definition, and my package structure... Please advise

**Comment by [adasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/52/adasta/) on 2011-09-01**:
could you post your arduino code?

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2011-08-31**:
It's getting weirder: after some fiddling with the rosserial code (added a couple of loginfo) it started to work. Then I had to delete and download again my (svn-based) code, and things don't work anymore...

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2011-08-25**:
Done: a publisher (Bool) and a subscriber (FLoat64). It works:  they are reported by the python_node alright.

**Comment by [adasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/52/adasta/) on 2011-08-25**:
In that same program, could you add a hello world publisher just to make sure that everything else is working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Brice,

You found a pretty tricky bug!    I guess we had never tried to run rosserial_python from within the package of a custom message.  Python automatically adds the working directory of a python executable to the python sys.path.  As a result, when rosserial_python went to check if it had the package in its sys.path, it found the current working directory. I just updated the code to check for the src directory of the package instead of just the package name.  It should work now.

Just pull the latest repo.

---

Originally posted by [adasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/52/adasta/) with karma: 508 on 2011-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2